# C# does array.length start from 0?

Tags: c#, arrays

I know that when you're referencing an array it starts from 0, but does array.length start from 0 or does it start from 1?

Because if I specify an array size to be 10, I reference it 0-9, does this mean array.length is 0-9?

I'm asking because I'm using array.length as the maximum size of a randomly generated number but I'm doing it like this

```
randomArrayPointer = randomIntNum( 0 , ( posPercents.Length - 1 ) ); //generates a random number that fits the arrays range
if( randomArrayPointer < posPercents.Length ) //ensures the integer is less than the length of the array
{
    return ( posPercents [ randomArrayPointer ] );
}
else
{
    return ( posPercents [ 0 ] );
}
```

Here is my method randomIntNumber (I +1 to the maximum because when specifying 1 to 10 as the inputs for Random() it will give me a number between 0-9)

```
public static int randomIntNum( int min , int max )
{
    if( max != 1 & ( max != ( min + 1 ) ) ) //if max isn't 1 and max isn't the minimum + 1
    {
        max = max - 1; //remove 1, this corrects the random generator so that the parameters sent don't need adjusting
    }
    int newInt;
    newInt =  rnd.Next( min , max );
    return ( newInt );
}
```

---

Edit:

This is my method now, thanks everyone.

```
    public static double randomPercentChange( Boolean? positive )
    {
        if( positive == true )
        {
            return ( posPercents [ rnd.Next( posPercents.Length ) ] );
        }
        else if( positive == false )
        {
            return ( negPercents [ rnd.Next( negPercents.Length ) ] );
        }
        else if( positive == null )
        {
            return ( 1 );
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

EDIT 2: 4 years on I am sorely embarrassed by this question, but it is a great reference point for progress

Comment: "does this mean array.length is 0-9?" that question doesn't make sense.  Length is as single value, and in your case it would be 10.

Comment: You mean what is the valid range of indices, and the answer is `0 .. array.Length - 1`. But `Length` will be whatever non-negative value you initialised the array as.

Comment: SO.... MUCH.... SPACING... please remove the excessive empty spaces.
CTRL+K+D!

Comment: For a random slot, you can simply use `myArray[myRandom.Next(myArray.Length)]`

Comment: @HenkHolterman that's the perfect solution to my problem, thanks!

Comment: Don't add an answer part to the question, post a self-answer instead.

Comment: If you just read the title to the question and the first answer, this page is actually really helpful to someone learning C#, so I upvoted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your array is empty, it contains 0 elements and has length 0.

If your array has 1 element in 0 index, then its length is equal to 1.

If your array has 2 elements in 0 and 1 indexes, then its length is equal 2.

and so on...

Comment: @MKasprzyk -- Accepting an answer won't close the question.

Comment: @MKasprzyk First, don't beg to accept an answer. Second, he can't accept your answer yet.

Comment: @ royap - ok i uderstand, but it is sign that correct answer was given. Am I right?

Comment: Who says you are correct? Who says someone else's answer isn't better? @MKasprzyk

Comment: @PatrickHofman the OP said it was correct in the first comment, and you shouldn't leave a question unanswered just because someone at some point might think of a better answer, though i agree that badgering the OP to mark an answer before they are ready to isn't a good idea either

Answer (score 0):

Array.Length refers to the size of the array, i.e how many elements it can hold. Arrays are 0 based when indexing them, so an example iteration would look like...

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
   var elm = myArray[i];
   //do something with the element
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I suppose your question is, "why is the last value in your array at index `posPercents.Length - 1` instead of `posPercents.Length`?"

Since arrays are zero based, `posPercents.Length = 10`, but the last value is not at index `10`. It is at index `9`, hence its index is `posPercents.Length - 1`.